# A custom control that extends update panel is marked false on server, still comes as a list of ids in response

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have a custom control that extends ASP.NET Update panels. On the server side if I go and mark it as Visible false, then the client side scripts moan saying panelsCreated[0] was not found.

On examining the response that comes back, I see that

|40|updatePanelIDs||fupd1,ftc$tab1,fUpdatePanel1,tupdFixAjax|20|childUpdatePanelIDs||

contains the id of my update panel. I am quite at a loss here as to why .NET would send the ID of my update panel in the response back when it has been hidden on server?

On a bog standard .NET update panel if you do this, the iD drops out of this bit in response that I have mentioned.

Any help will be appreciated.

PS: The control is quite complicated in its nature and does a lot more. However all that shouldn't really be changing this behaviour here. I do not override the Visible property of parent update panel control in my custom control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does every major breakthrough or epiphany happen in toilets!

I have managed to resolve this guys, a freak condition was toggling the visibility to true in my the customized parent container that houses my custom control. As a result the .NET framework was (rightly) pushing out the id of my control.